# Simulate HTTP requests from different location - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, functional-testing, geography

I've an asp.net application which shows some information to the users relevant to the country they are from. So I want to do functional testing on my application. How I can simulate HTTP requests to my application from different countries?

Comment: How are you determining their location. Using geo ip?

Comment: Yes. We are using an external service which gives us all the geographic details of an IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically use a proxy from another country. Do not forget to set the `HttpWebRequest.Proxy` property. See the MSDN article [Send an HTTP Request with Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172495.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use http proxies, there are plenty of them all around the world !

You just have to configure your browser to use one of them, and then open your website in it.

http://www.proxy-list.org/en/index.php